# Alfresco Share: how to use evaluator="aspect" to check for (parent) aspect

Tags: alfresco, evaluation, alfresco-share, evaluator

I have one aspect which is the parent aspect of two other aspects.

```
<aspect name="my:parentAspect">
</aspect> 

<aspect name="my:subAspect1">
    <parent>my:parentAspect</parent>
</aspect>

<aspect name="my:subAspect2">
    <parent>my:parentAspect</parent>
</aspect>
```

Now I want to use the "aspect"-evaluator in my share-config-custom to apply some customization if a node directly has the aspect "my:parentAspect" **or if the node has an aspect that has inherited from "my:parentAspect" by having it as a parent**.

```
<config evaluator="aspect" condition="my:subAspect1">...</config>
<config evaluator="aspect" condition="my:subAspect2">...</config>
```

works, but I would prefer to use

```
<config evaluator="aspect" condition="my:parentAspect">...</config>
```

because the configs for each subAspect are actually all the same.
However, this does not work for nodes that don't have the my:parentAspect directly attached bu only inheriting the aspect.

What's the best practice to check for an aspect regardless whether it's directly applied or inherited somewhere down the hierarchy?

Comment: These configs are independent of hierarchy It does not have knowledge about parent-child relationship. That kind of structure decoupled those aspects as they are not restricted to bind to any one of the type of any particular type so, this make sense to have this kind of structure.

Comment: The main evaluation logic happens in the specific evaluator, which is  evaluator.doclib.action.hasAspect (org.alfresco.web.evaluator.HasAspectEvaluator.java class, http://bit.ly/1buxd9d) in this case, where the evaluator knows it's explicitly dealing with aspects. An aspects, same as types, would always have an optional parent attribute, which could therefore be checked. However, it's only checking the direct aspects. From a business logic perspective, it would make sense to check for parents as well. Therefore I wonder if it hadn't commonly been needed already in the Alfresco community.

Comment: I understand that the configs are generic (decoupled), but the evaluators that they're using are quite specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

regarding your own comments: don't mix form configs & doclib configs!

org.alfresco.web.config.forms.AspectEvaluator is the Evaluator for form configs like

```
<config evaluator="aspect" condition="my:parentAspect">...</config>
```

org.alfresco.web.evaluator.HasAspectEvaluator.java is used for aspect-related evaluator within

```
<config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary">
```

e.g. for indicators, metadata-templates etc.
So, org.alfresco.web.config.forms.AspectEvaluator  is the one here. It's a subclass of [org.alfresco.web.config.forms.NodeMetadataBasedEvaluator](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/web-framework-commons/source/java/org/alfresco/web/config/forms/NodeMetadataBasedEvaluator.java) that uses the api/metadata Webscript to get the Metadata of the given node:

```
/api/metadata?nodeRef=" + nodeString + "&shortQNames=true"
```

This webscript uses org.alfresco.repo.jscript.ScriptNode.toJson() which only includes directly attached aspects.That could be your starting point for a custom Evalutor.